# Substituting string labels by integer IDs and back

Tags: vowpalwabbit

My data files contain lines with the first entity being a string label followed by features. For example:

```
MEMO |f write down this note
CALL |f call jim's cell
```

The problem is that Vowpal Wabbit accepts only integer labels. How can I quickly change from string labels to unique integer IDs and back? That is quickly modify the data file to:

```
1 |f write down this note
2 |f call jim's cell
```

... and back when needed.

For my sample dataset I did it manually for each class using ``sed'', but this breaks seriously my workflow.

Comment: Looking more carefully at the VW format, it is possible to add a tag string to each example (not necessarily unique). I think I will use it to store string labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat input.data | perl -nale '$i=$m{$F[0]}; $i or $i=$m{$F[0]}=++$n; $F[0]=$i; print "@F"; END{warn "$_ $m{$_}\n" for sort {$m{$a}<=>$m{$b}} keys %m}' > output.data 2> mapping.txt
```